# OpenLayers 3 : DragZoom, change shortcut from [Click + Shift] to [Click + Ctrl]

Tags: openlayers-3

I'm trying to change the default behavior of ol3 on his DragZoom event: i want this feature, by default configured on Click + <kbd>Shift</kbd>, working instead with Click + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.

Do you have any idea of how to perform that?

Already consulted the online doc:
http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.interaction.DragZoom.html

Seems to be a "condition" property, but can't figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "condition" value has to be a function that is called when the event occurs. OpenLayers doesn't come with a `ol.events.condition.ctrlKeyOnly`, but you could define your own.  You'd need to disable the default DragZoom interaction first, then add your own:

```
var interactions = ol.interaction.defaults({
  shiftDragZoom: false
});
interactions.push(new ol.interaction.DragZoom({
  duration: 200,
  condition: function(mapBrowserEvent) {
    var originalEvent = mapBrowserEvent.originalEvent;
    return (
      originalEvent.ctrlKey &&
      !(originalEvent.metaKey || originalEvent.altKey) &&
      !originalEvent.shiftKey);
  }
}));
```

See it in action in a [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e9j6jfL6/).

Comment: Many thanks Alexandre, that works perfectly! Thanks again for the quick answer and the fiddle.

Comment: What you might expect to be called `ol.events.condition.ctrlKeyOnly` is called `ol.events.condition.platformModifierKeyOnly` so `condition: ol.events.condition. platformModifierKeyOnly` would have been sufficient